# Missing DLL: print message instead of launching a popup

Tags: windows, dll

When an exe tries to load a missing DLL, windows will show a popup message. Is there any way to instead print something to stderr?

I'm open to code-level changes, but if there's a system-wide setting (registry?) that will print the message, instead of using a popup, that'd be great.

Comment: This normally happens before your code starts running.  There is no stderr yet.

Answer (score 1):

The [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) documentation contains the relevant hint:

> To enable or disable error messages displayed by the loader during DLL loads, use the [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621.aspx) function.

So you have to call [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621.aspx) to disable dialog boxes before trying to load the DLL. However this does not redirect the error to *stderr*. You have to catch the error yourself and print something to *stderr*.

Comment: The question isn't clear about whether the application is calling `LoadLibrary` or relying on Windows to dynamically link the DLL, but I'd assume the latter.